# function is not returning after creating a new class of an asynchronous timer

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock

I have a class that is creating an asynchronous timer that should run on the background. I have created a timer class that creates an object with its individual thread and should run in the background. On top of that I have two functions CreateTimer and DeleteTimer which will be used to access the timer class objects. My intention is to call the CreateTimer and DeleteTimer for multiple threads as well.  I have the following code:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>



typedef struct
{
    uint32_t  msgId;
    uint32_t  param1;
    uint32_t  param2;
}THRD_EVENT_T;


enum THRD_EVENTID_T
{
    THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST,

    THRD_STATEA,
    THRD_STATEB,
    THRD_STATEC,

    THRD_MSGID_TIMER_LAST
};

std::mutex m;





void func_(THRD_EVENTID_T timerId_, int32_t pipeId_ )
{

    std::cout<<"done\n";
}


class Timer 
{

public:
    Timer(THRD_EVENTID_T timerId, int32_t pipeId, uint32_t msPeriod)
        : timerId_(timerId)
        , pipeId_(pipeId)
        , msPeriod_(msPeriod)
    {

    }


    Timer(const Timer &obj) // copy constructor
    {
        timerId_ = obj.timerId_;
        pipeId_ = obj.pipeId_;
        msPeriod_ = obj.msPeriod_; 
    }
    // Timer()
    // {

    // }

    Timer() = delete;
    Timer(Timer&&) = default;


    ~Timer() 
    {
        if (thread_.joinable())
            thread_.join();
    }

    void start()
    {
        std::cout<<"starting the timer\n";
        thread_ = std::thread
        { 
             [this]() 
            {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex_);
            cv_.wait_for(lck, msPeriod_, [this]() { return stop_waiting_.load(); });
            if (not stop_waiting_)
                func_(timerId_, pipeId_);
            }
        };
    }

    void stop()
    {
        stop_waiting_.store(true);
        std::cout<<"Stopping the timer\n";
        cv_.notify_one();
    }

    THRD_EVENTID_T GetTimerID()
    {
        return timerId_;
    }

private:
    std::chrono::milliseconds msPeriod_;
    THRD_EVENTID_T timerId_;
    int32_t pipeId_;
    std::thread thread_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::atomic<bool> stop_waiting_{false};
};


std::vector<Timer> tmrclass;

int32_t CreateTimer( const THRD_EVENTID_T timerId, const int32_t pipeId, const uint32_t msPeriod )
{
    std::cout<<"Creating the timer\n";
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);

    Timer c (timerId, pipeId, msPeriod);

    tmrclass.emplace_back(c);

    c.start();

    std::cout<<"exiting the createtimer function\n";

    std::cout<<"returning....\n";
    return 0;

}


int32_t Delete_Timer( const THRD_EVENTID_T timerId)
{
    int32_t ret = -1;
    std::cout<<"Deleting the timer function\n";
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);

    for (auto &f : tmrclass)
    {
        if(f.GetTimerID() == timerId)
        {
            std::cout<<"found the timer to delete\n";
            f.stop();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ret = -1;
        }

    }

     return ret;
}


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) 
{

    THRD_EVENTID_T timerId;
    timerId  =  THRD_STATEA;
    int32_t pipeId = 0;
    uint32_t msPeriod = 5000;

    CreateTimer(timerId, pipeId, msPeriod);
    std::cout<<"Have I exited the resource\n";

    THRD_EVENTID_T timerId2;
    timerId2  =  THRD_STATEB;
    int32_t pipeId2 = 1;
    uint32_t msPeriod2 = 1000;
    CreateTimer(timerId2, pipeId2, msPeriod2);

    Delete_Timer(timerId);


    return 0;
}
```

When I run it the code isn't returning from the `CreateTimer` function it ends up being stuck after printing out `returning....` I cant figure out why it is not returning from the `CreateTimer` function

Comment: Because your `Timer c` is a local variable and your destructor `join()`s on it, most likely. This would be a good time to break out your debugger and _inspect_ the actual system in the "hung" state instead of relying on output and guesswork.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: A debugger is a good suggestion. If you don't want to use one for some reason, add more diagnostic output. When you feel stuck, add a diagnostic after every line of code (other than other diagnostics, of course). This becomes easier if you reduce your code to a [mre] -- for example, get rid of all data members and parameters that are not needed to reproduce the problem. In particular, `Delete_Timer` can be eliminated (as it is never reached) as can all the parameters you use to locate the timer to delete. `CreateTimer` can likely have no parameters when your goal is to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the destruction of the `c` object, which attempts to [`join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) the thread. It will block until the thread is finished. This causes a *deadlock* because there's no-one to tell the thread to exit.

For a truly independent timer you need the thread to be [detached](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach). Or you need to use some other design (single-threaded event-loops are commonly used). Or use OS-native timers instead.

Comment: How exactly would I use detached? Do I need to keep track of the threads then after they have been detached?

Comment: @newww issue is that your "createtimer" does not only create a timer, it also immediately destroys it. That is perhaps what you do not want it to do. Running thread operating on destroyed object detached is certainly very bad idea.

Comment: @newww It's actually worse than I first thought... You create a copy of the `Timer` object `c` when you add it to the vector, but you keep ownership of the thread in the `c` object. Threads can't be copied, only *moved*. You need to think more in terms of *ownership* instead, and to *move* the object `c` to be owned by the vector instead.

Comment: @newww Instead of transferring ownership of the timer object to the vector, you could *create* the timer object inside the vector directly. Instead of `tmrclass.emplace_back(c);` you can do `tmrclass.emplace_back(timerId, pipeId, msPeriod);`. Then you don't need the `c` object at all. I also recommend you mark the copy-constructor as deleted, since `Timer` objects can't really be copied.